# How to change GUI on DVD?

Tags: installation, nvidia, screen

I downloaded Edubuntu 12.04 LTS DVD and when I boot from it, all I get is a white screen, after selecting to install or run from DVD.  I'm almost sure it is a graphic card problem since I'm using NVDIA GeForce 6100 nForce 405/PCI/SSE2. I tried to update but it'll take too long and I don't have the time.

My PC is AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4200+ × 2 with 8Gb Ram and Edubuntu 11.10 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting the install DVD on a different computer in order to verify that it is an issue with the GPU/Driver as opposed to an issue with the install medium?

If the problem is indeed a lack of out-of-the-box support for your graphics card, you may need to perform a installation in text-only mode. As far as I know, there is no "Alternate Installation" (i.e. text-only) .iso image of Edubuntu available to download, so if you have your heart set on upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04, I think your options are: 1) Start the update before you go to bed/work/wherever, so the time will not be an issue, or  2) perform a text-only installation of the standard Ubuntu desktop using the Alternate Install .iso [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/), then activate whatever drivers with which you are currently having success on 11.10, and proceed to essentially convert your new Ubuntu installation to Edubuntu with the very simple instructions [here](http://edubuntu.org/download). The latter option would obviously take longer and be more of a hassle, though there are certainly positive things to be said about fresh installations as opposed to upgraded installations in most cases.